# What is this sub object mode addon in the pic?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I've been looking for this for a long time so that I'm able to select my sub-object modes by holding a button like I do in Maya.

I saw this video that is using this but I have no idea what addon it is? Does anyone know?
Thanks

Comment: It is called MACHIN3tools. You can find it here: https://gumroad.com/l/machin3tools